# Best way to store relational data in hdfs

Tags: sql, hadoop, hdfs

I've been reading a lot on hadoop lately and I can say that I understand the general concept of it, but there is still (at least)one piece of the puzzle that I can't get my head around. What is the best way to store relationnal data in hdfs.

First of all, I know that hadoop does not exist to replace my conventional good old sql database that serve my application. The problem that I'm facing here is that I would like to use hadoop to aggregate data from multiple systems into hdfs. I can then cross-reference data from multiple system together and then produce new set of data used by my reporting tools etc.

Alright, so, should I import tables data using one table to one file or should I import the results of queries that join tables.

For example:

> SQL tables:
>
> Person:
>       PersonID
>       Name
>       Birthday
>       Sex
>
> Company:

```
CompanyID
Name
Address
```

> PersonCompany

```
PersonID
CompanyID
```

Should I import all 3 table as is or should I import the result of the query returns why person works for which company.

Please share your thought with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically to build a data warehouse in hadoop, you have to ingest all the tables. In your example you need to have all 3 tables in HDFS and then do the ETL/aggregation for example Joiners_weekly can have a etl which have

select * from PersonCompany pc join Person p on pc.personid=p.personid join Company c on pc.companyid=c.companyid.

This can be a report which can be generated from hadoop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gaurav. Regarding tables importation, would you suggest to import them all every days and overwrite the file in hdfs, create a new file at every importation or create a new file with only the new records?

Comment: This decision goes with the type of data. If you have updates in your table it is advisable to do a full overwrite, but if the data to huge to do full overwrite daily you have to do incremental import and then de-duplicate the records based on primary key(This has to be done using separate pig/hive job). If the table is not updated at all you can go for incremental import without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using HBase on top of HDFS to get some Database functionality:

http://hbase.apache.org/

Comment: This is has been considered and will be implemented, but my question is more aimed toward the structure of data to import.

Comment: It is probably best to join all tables into one "big table", as this is what HBase is meant to handle.